# html custom new tag and get new tag content

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, custom-attributes

i found my self in the past few days interesting in html custom tags so i decided to give it a shot , i haven't found a lot of information on the web but i got some results , i think.

here is the code i reached so far

```
<html>
   <body>

     <newtag>ds</newtag>

     <script type="text/javascript">
        var newtag = document.getElementsByTagName('newtag');
        alert(newtag.innerHTML);
     </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

the alert is giving me the value "undefined" ,

i don't really know if what i have done is good , and if the syntax to suppose to be write like this , and i don't know even if the html custom tag is possible

- is it possible to create custom html tag?
- what is the problem in my code?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "getElementsByTagName()" function returns a node list:

```
alert(newtag[0].innerHTML);
```

You can treat the node list as an array, though it's not really an instance of Array.

Comment: thank you , this was that simple and i learned a new thing , thanks. i will mark as solve as soon as i can.